# Что означает stalled в timeline dev tools при использовании протокола SPDY

Tags: google-chrome

Что означает stalled (Большие значение порядка 300-400мс) в timeline dev tools при использовании протокола SPDY?

Ведь судя по описанию протокола, все идет частями через одно подключение. 
А в описании к [dev-tools network](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#view-network-timing-details-for-a-specific-resource) про stalled написано:

> Time the request spent waiting before it could be sent. This time is inclusive of any time spent in proxy negotiation. Additionally, this time will include when the browser is waiting for an already established connection to become available for re-use, obeying Chrome's maximum six TCP connection per origin rule.

Как я думал, при использовании SPDY браузер не должен ждать установления соединения, ведь оно всего одно и данные идут частями.

[image: SCREEN1]